# forEach function with Extra parameters

Tags: javascript, recursion, foreach, bind

Hey so I have a simple function below to walkTheDOM recursively that I want to add some additional features to.

```
function walkTheDOM(node) {
    if( node.hasChildNodes() ) {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(node.children, walkTheDOM );
    } 
}
```

Additional functionality so that I can apply something to each function. Using `applyFn` to perform an action on each element that the function traverses.

```
function walkTheDOM(node,applyFn) {
    //do something to each node
    !applyFn || applyFn(node);
    if( node.hasChildNodes() ) {
        forEach.call(node.children, function(childNode){ return walkTheDOM(childNode, applyFn); } );
    } else {
        console.log("Is Leaf:", node);   
    }
}
```

I would like to clean the code up to be similar to the first code sample, specifically this line:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(node.children, walkTheDOM );
```

So that it calls the applyFn without having to wrap the `walkTheDOM` function inside of a function.

Is it possible to do this by idk something like calling `forEach.call(child, walkTheDom.call(child, applyFn)`?

Basically, is there anyway to add additional parameters to this function inherently without creating this sort of configuration where an external anonymous function is wrapping my recursive call to add my parameter of applyFn (apply function)?

I'm not concerned with using some sort of jQuery function or other library to complete this task so please don't answer with another way to accomplish the task, such as, "Look into jQuery lib XYZ..." or "jQuery already does this, try jQuery.libXYZ..." etc... I am simply exploring recursion and function calls in JavaScript. I don't care about some other third party that already does this function, this is my question. Thanks.

**EDIT**
Maybe this can be understood better by this code which is more of a classical approach.

```
function walkTheDOM(node, applyFn) {
    applyFn(node);
    if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
        for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
            walkTheDOM(node.children[i],applyFn);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably you want to use `.bind()` to add arguments to a callback.  But, honestly, I can't quite tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm asking if I can pass a function to `Array.prototype.forEach` with an additional parameter (that is a function) that will be applied to each item being iterated over, basically.

Comment: I have `walkTheDOM(node, applyFunction)` so, forEach(walkTheDOM) works. I need this to pass with applyFunction so it can be applied within the function inherently.

Comment: And, I'm suggesting you read how to use `.bind()` to do that.

Comment: Honestly, I couldn't tell exactly what you were suggesting.

Comment: Did you even look up what `.bind()` does?  Excuse me for offering a suggestion.  I will leave now.

Comment: Not sure how you can offer a suggestion if you can't quite tell what I'm asking...

Comment: Seriously?  You want to mock those who try to help.  Good luck here doing that.  It appears you're trying to add arguments to a callback.  That's one of the things that `.bind()` will do for you.  I don't understand the question well enough to offer a more specific answer than that.  You can research `.bind()` yourself to see what it does.

Comment: Buddy, relax. I think I understand `.bind()` a bit and I do appreciate your comment I think you have a good point. I am going to look into it some more, I think it can maybe accomplish what I'm looking for but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

var root = document.getElementById("root");

function applyFn(element, index) {
    // do stuff         
    if (element.hasChildNodes()) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("result")[0].innerHTML += "<br>Do something with this node: " + element.className; 
      walkTheDOM(element)
    } else {
        console.log("Is Leaf:", element);   
    }  
}

function walkTheDOM(node) {
    if( node.hasChildNodes() ) {
        forEach.call(node.children, applyFn);
    } else {
        console.log("Is Leaf:", node);   
    }    
}

walkTheDOM(root);
```

```html
<div id="root" class="parent1">
    <div class="1-child1">
        <div class="1-child1-child1"></div>
        <div class="1-child1-child2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent2">
        <div class="2-child1"></div>
        <div class="2-child2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent3"></div>
</div>


<p class="result"></p>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zcwc633k/4/

Comment: I will look at this but I don't think it will work. Calling walkTheDOM on node.children wont work. I would have to iterate the children twice with this solution ie: `forEach.call(node.children, walkTheDOM)` I think I could declare applyFn outside of recursive function though and call it through each iteration...

Comment: _"will look at this but I don't think it will work. Calling walkTheDOM on node.children wont work"_ ? See at OP _"would like to clean the code up to be similar to the first code sample, specifically this line:

`Array.prototype.forEach.call(node.children, walkTheDOM );`"_ ? Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Yeah, I mean this works but it's not very effecient because it is traversing the array twice. Also, you can see this jsfiddle for another working solution which is (maybe) optimal. http://jsfiddle.net/zcwc633k/3/ ... I know that it's better, I think it's linear time... I think, I'm not sure. haha. Anyway, it's better. Not sure if it's best.

Comment: @nf071590 See original post at _"would like to clean the code up to be similar to the first code sample, specifically this line:"_ ? http://jsfiddle.net/zcwc633k/3/ appear to be similar , same as second block at Question ? If http://jsfiddle.net/zcwc633k/3/ resolves Question , perhaps post , accept own answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer ?

Comment: Yeah, my question still isn't answered. I am looking for a solution where I can extend the functions parameters of `walkTheDOM` during each forEach loop. I am going to try and implement this with bind from @jfriend00 's suggestion.

Comment: @nf071590 _"Yeah, my question still isn't answered. I am looking for a solution where I can extend the functions parameters of walkTheDOM during each forEach loop."_ Question not very clear as to actual requirement ?

Comment: I added another example which may help clarify. I'm looking to pass in my applyFn down into the recursive calls basically using forEach... You may be able to see more clearly in the new example.

Comment: Maybe the only way is here... http://jsfiddle.net/zcwc633k/6/  ... using some function wrappers, etc... or is there a way to bind my applyFn callback to walkTheDOM during runtime. That is what I'm looking for

Comment: @nf071590 Still not certain about required pattern , expected result ? Or if a particular pattern model is requirement ? If element has child nodes , do stuff , call function on child nodes , else log node to console ?

Comment: Pass a function to walkTheDOM that acts on each node of the DOM.  My question is related to syntax I would suggest. Is this possible with a specific syntax.... Can I simply say `function walkTheDOM(node, callback) {
    if( node.hasChildNodes() ) {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(node.children, walkTheDOM );
    } 
}` using bind or some other syntax that elimates the need to wrap walkTheDOM in a function when it's being called by the forEach mehtod as its argument. If so, how can I do this?

Comment: I'd suggest that the callback function needs to be bound to the walkTheDOM function so that it can reference the callback during recursion. Otherwise the callback is lost.

Comment: _"Can I simply say function walkTheDOM(node, callback) { if( node.hasChildNodes() ) { Array.prototype.forEach.call(node.children, walkTheDOM ); } }"_ Yes, though why would `callback` be included at that pattern ? Same , similar to one of patterns already included at original post ? There appear to be solutions to Question both at Question , and above ? Not certain what particular pattern _style_ have preference for ? If one of solutions return expected results, perhaps utilize that pattern ; or revise , create clearer Question ?

Comment: Which portion of solution above does not return expected results ?

Comment: @nf071590 _"forget it.. nevermind "_ ? Is Question resolved ?

Answer (score 1):

This avoids duplicate traversing...

```
function applyMe(node){
    console.log(node)
}
function walkTheDOM(node) {

    if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
        applyMe(node)
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(node.children, walkTheDOM)
    } else {
        applyMe(node)
    }

}

var node = document.getElementById('container');

walkTheDOM(node)
```

Comment: Thank's you're right. See the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/zcwc633k/5/ which is pretty much the same thing